# Twitter post API C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter

I want post replay for a twitter from my C# web application. I have twitter token in my database. How we can do this

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "replay" but there is a library for .NET called [TweetSharp](http://code.google.com/p/tweetsharp/) that will probably do what you want.